# how to find the number of elements in an array

Tags: c

I have an int array  and I need to find the number of elements in it. I know it has something to do with sizeof but I'm not sure how to use it exactly. example

```
 int data2[]={a,b,c,d};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With an array you can do:

```
int numElements = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
```

But this only works with arrays, and won't work if you've passed the array to a function: at that point the array decays to a pointer, and so `sizeof` will return the size of the pointer.

You'll see this wrapped up in a macro:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof (x)[0])
```

Comment: +1. It's a good idea to stick this in a macro, since if you copy and paste it to use it on a different array you can forget to change one of the occurrences of `data`: `#define lengthof(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof (x)[0])`

Comment: @j_random_hacker I call that ARRAY_LENGTH since that's the only thing it can take the length of.