# Using argc to control range of for loop

Tags: c

this is my code. For some reason it gets stuck in an infinite loop(the first for loop). The purpose of this codes it to get a command line arg and the user enters that many arguments and the rest of the program prints the smallest number. Thanks in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int array[argc]; 
    int smallest;   
    for(int i=0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("Welcome to number comparator!\n");
        printf("Enter command line # of numbers(enter delimitater):");
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            smallest=array[i]; 
        else if(array[i] < array[i-1]) 
        {
            smallest=array[i]; 
        }
    }
}
printf("The smallest number is %d", smallest);

    return 0; 

}
```

Edit: This is not the same as getting an array of integers from cmd line. the cmd line argument is only to enter how many arguments should be entered. Essentially, if I run ./a.out 5. I enter 5 numbers after that and the smallest should be returned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find the number of elements in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646821/how-to-find-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: The array size and the number of elements in an array are different. You want the latter which is `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);`

Comment: argc is the number of parameters passed

Comment: `char *argv[]` is the array of arguments being passed to main, and `argv[0]` is always the program name, so `argv[1]` is the value which you need to use instead of `argc`.

Comment: The code shown won't compile; you have a `printf()`, and a `return` that are outside any function, and a close brace with no matching open brace.  I'm not sure why the `if` doesn't need braces but the `else` does; consistency suggests you should choose one style or the other.  I'd forego the braces after the else, but not everyone would agree with that.

Comment: Note that you could use: `smallest = array[0]; for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { if (array[i] < smallest) smallest = array[i]; }` which would both be neater and more efficient and also more likely to be correct.  If you have an array with values 1, 10, 20, 19 you'll end up with `smallest` equal to 19, which is not conventionally considered the smallest of those four numbers.

Comment: @Jonathan I think like +piyushj suggested, he is only entering one argument, so he'd want `argv[1]` and not `argc` (really `atoi(argv[1])`) for the `for` loop limit. Also, +Nithin, note that you could just use this instead of `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]` (note the space since, much like `return`, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, and it only needs parenthesis around a type, e.g. `sizeof (int)`. It really doesn't make much difference but this is really the way it was meant to be used but you may do as you please :) ). Also, you'd probably want those two `printf`s to be prior to . . .

Comment: @RastaJedi: the program could be invoked as `./myprog 1 2 3 4 5` to get `argc == 6`, but I don't dispute that using `atoi(argv[1])` (after checking that there is a non-null `argv[1]`, and that the value returned by `atoi()` is neither zero nor negative) is more sensible.

Comment: . . . the `for` loop and `scanf()`, so that it only shows once, and note you can encode the number directly into your `printf`, e.g. `printf("Welcome to number comparator!\nPlease enter %d numbers to compare: ", atoi(argv[1]));`. You will need `<stdlib.h>` for `atoi()`. You probably also want a `\n` in your last `printf` too; I'm not sure if editing that in there is acceptable. Sorry that the second part of my comment was so late it came after Jonathan's. Yes @Jonathan that would be what he would have to do, but I think his intention was to just enter one argument. It was mostly a note for OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've completely misunderstood how C passes command line arguments.  You also have more closing brackets than opening brackets.  And your statement order could use some adjustment.

Here's a rework of your code addressing the above issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int length = atoi(argv[1]);

    int array[length];  

    printf("Welcome to number comparator!\n");
    printf("Enter %d number(s): ", length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        (void) scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    int smallest = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = array[i];
        }
    }

    printf("The smallest number is %d\n", smallest);

    return 0;
}
```

This isn't finished code, you still need to do some error checking: make sure a command line value was passed `argc > 1`; check that the command line value is a number; verify that `scanf()` sucessfully reads in the numbers; etc.

Comment: Why do you have `(void) scanf() ...`?

Comment: @iharob, `scanf()` returns a useful value that's being ignored.  I put the `(void)` in front to remind myself (or others) that there was a potential error check I could have done but didn't so when the program fails, or I'm ready to finish it off correctly, this is a weak spot to revisit.  Personal hang-up.

Comment: I like your answer very much, but use a comment for that. I think that this way, you also silence some compiler warning.

Comment: Note that variable-length arrays are a feature of C99 and above, but can be used with C90/C90 code via GNU extensions (`-std=gnu90` [or equivalently `gnu89`] and I believe may even be enabled with `-std=c90` [or equivalently `c89`; `-ansi` also achieves same result]  unless you specify `-pedantic`). Up until very recently, GCC used the `gnu90` dielect by default (now `gnu11` is the default). Also, @iharob, I don't think that not using `(void)` to explicitly ignore return values ever flags a compiler warning, but doing so does suppress warnings from certain tools such as 'lint'.

Comment: @RastaJedi This comment is irrelevant. Modern OS's will ship modern versions of *gcc* and they will be at least *c99* by default. And regarding the warning, I think MSVC compiler does warn about not using the return value.

Comment: @iharob up until _extremely_ recently, GCC used `gnu90` by default. It now uses `gnu11`. There was never a time when GCC used `gnu99` or `c99` by default, as far as I know. Also, not everyone is using GCC so they might not find VLA support. I have yet to see a system that has GCC using anything other than `gnu90` by default, but as I said, this change was very recent and I haven't updated my systems in a while. **EDIT:** Looks like it was maybe towards the end of last year, whenever GCC 5.0 came out.